# Tricomi Hypergeometric U in Python

Tags: python

There is ***sympy*** package in Python for doing symbolic computation. It has most of the hypergeometric functions. However, I am unable to find the specific [Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function.](http://functions.wolfram.com/webMathematica/FunctionEvaluation.jsp?name=HypergeometricU)

My requirement is pretty basic. For e.g. if we specify U(a,b,x), I want to get the first 5-10 terms of this expansion. ***sympy*** package has the *expand* function but it does not have the Tricomi hypergeometric U function. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: 
As some users suggested, I set out to write my own function. However, I am unable to expand even the basic ones. Can someone give a reproducible example for me to play around with? Thank you

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
expand_func(hyper([y],[z],x))
```

Comment: so define it yourself?

Comment: I was trying to avoid it as I am pretty sure it should be defined as it is a widely used function.

Comment: perhaps it's just not that widely used after all? In fact, it's not in any standard math lib I know of.

Comment: Can you please go through the edited question now? Thank you!

Comment: I presume that you can't use Numpy?

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing this issue. The thing is, `scipy.special.hyp1f1` is Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function and not Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function — see this [mathematica](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/02/) page for connection between them. There is also a point of confusion in that scipy.special.hyperu is not what we want here, even though the name 'hyperu' suggests otherwise. I don't know what scipy.special.hyperu is, but it is not Tricomi's version. I have checked.

To get Tricomi's version, use the formula given in above link:

```
U(a,b,z)=\frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a+1-b)}1F1(a,b,z)+\frac{\Gamma(b-1)}{\Gamma(a)}z^{1-b}1F1(a+1-b,2-b,z)
```

Here, `1F1` is [Kummer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric1F1.html)'s version, or `scipy.special.hyp1f1`, and `U(a,b,z)` is Tricomi's version. Use the following Python code to convert one to another:

```py
from scipy.special import gamma, hyp1f1

def U(a, b, z):
    # First term of the equation
    term1 = gamma(1 - b) / gamma(a + 1 - b) * hyp1f1(a, b, z)

    # Second term of the equation
    term2 = gamma(b - 1) / gamma(a) * z**(1 - b) * hyp1f1(a + 1 - b, 2 - b, z)

    # Combine the terms
    result = term1 + term2
    return result


print(U(5/4,1/2,1/4))
```

The output should be 0.774599815892687, which I have confirmed using mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

As of scipy version 1.9.0, an implementation of Tricomi's (confluent hypergeometric) function is included in `scipy.special` as `scipy.special.hyperu`. Documentation for this function can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.hyperu.html?highlight=confluent%20hypergeometric%20function).